# Using multiple values in a filter function jquery data attribute example

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I was looking at the usage of jquery filter for data attributes, in this case, tables containing three data variables, i.e, team, specialization and level. Please do let me know what the best approach is and what the typical usage methodology are. 
Here is my code html:

```
<table data-team="<?php print $name['team']; ?>" data-specialization="<?php print $name['speciality']; ?>" data-level="<?php print $name['level']; ?>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="670px" class="jobs"><tr><td>
            <tr><td colspan="4"><strong><?php print $name['title'] ?></strong></td>
            <td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="100">Location : </td>
            <td colspan="3"><?php print ($name['location']);?> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> Job Code : </td>
            <td width="460"><?php print $name['id'] ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td> 
            <td><a data-action="showDesc,jumpTo" href="javascript:;" id="<?php print($name['id']);?>" class="more">More Details </a></td>
            </tr></td></tr>
        </table>
```

The javascript that I have I got from one other Stack Overflow question, and it works on showing based on one matching attribute, here is my code:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
            var team=$('#selectOne').val();
            var specialty=$('#selectTwo').val();
            var level=$('#selectThree').val();
            var teams=[];// 
            var special=[];
            var level=[];
            //teams=$('.jobs').data('team');
            //alert(teams);

                    $(".jobs").hide();
                        $('.jobs').filter(function(){
                                    return $(this).data('team') === team;
                                }).show();
                            });
   });
```

I want to put all the data-team  attributes into the array, iterate over it and then check if each table contains it, in which case to the next array, to check and so on. if the data values match then, show.

Comment: Turns out my error was that I reassigned the levels variable to an array thereby emptying it, it works just fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my error was just that I re-declared the variables team[]. so basically, this:

```
$('.jobs')  .hide().filter('[data-team="'+team+'"][data-specialization="'+specialty+'"][data-level="'+level+'"]').addClass('num').show();
```

Works fine now.